# SQL: Matching parents and children from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

First time working with `SQL`. I have table `Person(personID, name, parentID1, parentID2)`. Parents are included in the table. I have to return table Result(child, parent). If the child has no parents, they are not included. If the child has two parents, the child is listed twice next to each parent.

Exact table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Person]
(
    personID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    parentID1 INT,
    parentID2 INT,
    gender VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Person

SELECT 25, 'Jack', 255, NULL, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 13, 'Jill', 100, 101, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 82, 'Adam', NULL, 200, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 100, 'Jeff', NULL, NULL, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 101, 'June', NULL, NULL, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 200, 'Shirley', NULL, NULL, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 155, 'Alice', 255, NULL, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 255, 'Tom', NULL, NULL, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 19, 'Jake', 100,101, 'Male'
```

Comment: what have you already tried if anything? What has or hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive join would give you what you are looking for. Something like this should work.

```
select  p1.name as child, 
        p2.name as parent 
from    dbo.[Person] p1 
    join dbo.[Person] p2
        on p1.parentID1 = p2.personID
        or p1.parentID2 = p2.personID
order by p1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Union statement should suffice:

```
    SELECT PersonID AS Child
          ,ParentID1 AS Parent
    FROM dbo.Person p1
    WHERE ParentID1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT PersonID AS Child
          ,ParentID2 AS Parent
    FROM dbo.Person p2
    WHERE ParentID2 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a self-join. Notice the aggregate to get combine the parents into a single row.

```
select
    max(case when t1.gender = 'Female' then t1.name end) as Mother
    ,max(case when t1.gender = 'Male' then t1.name end) as Father
    ,t2.name as Child
    ,t2.gender as ChildGender
from 
    Person t2 
    inner join Person t1 on t1.personID = t2.parentID1 or t1.personID = t2.parentID2
group by
    t2.name 
    ,t2.gender
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DZJRI64984)

**RETURNS**

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
|    | Mother  | Father | Child | ChildGender |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | NULL    | Tom    | Alice | Female      |
|  2 | June    | Jeff   | Jill  | Female      |
|  3 | Shirley | NULL   | Adam  | Male        |
|  4 | NULL    | Tom    | Jack  | Male        |
|  5 | June    | Jeff   | Jake  | Male        |
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Please check the Image with the output ]**

SELECT NAME,parentID1 AS parentID FROM person WHERE parentID1  IS NOT NULL
UNION

SELECT NAME,parentID2 AS parentID  FROM person WHERE parentID2  IS NOT NULL;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoU2H.png